# wp_login_form() redirect same page

Tags: redirect, login, wp-login-form

Im trying to redirect same page using wp_login_form(). this is my code

```
function loginform() {
if ( is_user_logged_in()){
echo '<p> <a  href="'.esc_url(home_url('/my-dashboard/')).'" >'.esc_html( __( 'Thank you.! Please Go to dashboard', 'mytheme' )).'</a></p>';}
else{
$args = array('redirect' => home_url(), 'id_username' => 'user','id_password' => 'pass',);
wp_login_form( $args );}}
add_shortcode('login-form', 'loginform');
```

i chancged the default wp-login.php url by using this filter

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'new_login_page', 10, 3 );
function new_login_page( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {$login_page = esc_url(home_url( '/login/'));return add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', $redirect, $login_page );}
```

then called to non logged in users to log in current page they are in by adding this code to

```
echo '<a href="'. esc_url(wp_login_url( get_permalink())) .'"><span class="icon" ></span>'.esc_html( __( 'login', 'mytheme' )).'</a> ';
```

everything work , but after logged in it wont redirect to previous page.. any help? highly appreciate.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after logged in it wont redirect to previous page

It's because in your `loginform()` function, the `'redirect' => home_url()` below sets the redirect URL to the homepage URL:

```php
$args = array('redirect' => home_url(), 'id_username' => 'user','id_password' => 'pass',);
```

So if you want to redirect to the previous page, then **remove** the `redirect` argument above, or use the code below, which means if `redirect_to=<URL>` is present in the current URL as in `example.com/login/?redirect_to=https://example.com/some-page/`, then the specified URL will be used instead:

```php
// Define your $args like this:
$args = array( 'id_username' => 'user', 'id_password' => 'pass' );

// Then add the 'redirect', if the URL has the redirect_to=<URL>.
if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
    $args['redirect'] = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
}
```

See the [`wp_login_form()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/) for more details on the `redirect` and other arguments.

### Additional Notes

Excerpt from [codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output):

> The return value of a shortcode handler function is inserted into the
> post content output in place of the shortcode macro. **Remember to use
> return and not echo - anything that is echoed will be output to the
> browser, but it won't appear in the correct place on the page.**

Therefore your `loginform()` should actually **return** the output and not echoing it (or anything else), because in addition to the above issue (shortcode appearing in the wrong place), an `echo` in the function would result in a failure in saving a post via the block editor (Gutenberg) which uses the REST API (so if your function echo something, the REST API response will be invalid).

So in that function, change the `echo '<p>` to *`return '<p>`*, then in the `$args` array, *add `'echo' => false`*, and finally change the `wp_login_form( $args )` to *`return wp_login_form( $args )`*.

Comment: Dear @Sally CJ. thank you very much for the Answer of my question. yes its worked :) . i really appreciate your help..! and Big thanks for the Instruction above . i learn lot form it..! thank you :)